# Dependency convergence coming from same Dependency- awssdk S3

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, dependency-management, aws-sdk-java-2.0

While working with aws sdk v2 for java, i had encounter with some issues.

i had included the DynamboDb and S3 dependencies and tried to run Maven install.

the problem is that the same dependency- S3, tried to fetch different versions of netty-handler.

this error was shown:

```
and
  +-software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.5.49
    +-software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:2.5.49
      +-io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.33.Final
and
  +-software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.5.49
    +-software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:2.5.49
      +-com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams-http:2.0.0
        +-com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:2.0.0
          +-io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.13.Final
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the convergence error by defining a version in your `dependencyManagement` section. If you don't know which version, it is advisable to use the newest of the confliciting ones and try.

It is not unusual that both conflicting dependencies are from beneath the same direct dependency.

Comment: Hey , thanks for the help. can you provide more details? i'm not sure- which version are you talking about? the base dependency or the "trouble" one?

Comment: You need to add an entry to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your `pom.xml`, which sets the version of `netty-handler` to the one you want, probably `4.1.33.Final`.